# Upgrading Cassandra from 1.2.10 to 2.0.1

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to upgrade a cassandra single node installation from 1.2.10 to 2.0.1.

I am using still the old RandomPartitioner, I change all the parameters in the cassandra.yaml file. But when I tried to start the node I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't open incompatible SSTable! Current version jb
```

In the notes from the documentation I can not find anything related with the change in the SSTables, did anyone deal with this problem?

Comment: Version jb is for 2.0.1. Are you sure you are running 2.0.1? is it possible you upgraded but then tried to go back to launching 1.2.10? Also, did you change the partitioner in the yaml? You shouldn't - changing partitioners is unsupported if you have existing data.

Comment: We are running in 2.0.1, but some of the column familys were created using older versions of cassandra and move the data between the differents upgrades.
When I say we change the partitioner, I refer to the default one. We are using Random Partitioner because was the one with which we start.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys had previously upgraded from an earlier version to 1.2.10, did you guys perform a 'nodetool upgradesstables'? This would have upgraded sstables to prevent possible incompatibilities.

The upgrade procedure from 1.2.9 to 2.x does not seem to recommend running it, so those sstables should be compatible, but trying it again might be worth it.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/#upgrade/upgradeC_c.html#task_ds_gqm_vzr_ck